# How to change the displayed title of a soft keyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, soft-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension, iphone-softkeyboard

Here's how my soft keyboard's title is currently displayed among the keyboard choices in iOS:

[image]

I'd prefer for it to be displayed like the Gboard example above it, simply as "ASETNIOP" on the top line and "Multiple languages" below, as shown in the mockup here:

[image]

I can change the lowercased prefix if I modify the extension's "Display Name" in Target->General->Identity, but I can't eliminate it (or the associated dash) entirely:

[image]

And (although I don't actually need to do this) it doesn't look like it's possible to change the main application's Display Name at all - it's grayed out:

[image]

Can anyone let me know where I need to go to make these changes, and where I need to go to change the Language designation as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For multi language, open your info.plist as source code of **extension part**. 
Then find

```
 <key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
    <string>en-US</string>
```

replace with

```
<key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
    <string>mul</string>
```

Comment: Found it under the NSExtension and then NSExtensionAttributes groups and it worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: @asetniop , how you solved your naming problem? i actually need that hep.

Comment: See @Yevhen Dubinin's answer below - I only needed to change the Bundle Display Name to get the results I wanted but his answer seems to cover everything you might want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the keyboard application extension (or *appex*) iOS displays in the menu under "Globe" button is taken from the Keyboard appex's metadata. In your case this is **asentitop** target. So, check/apply the following for this target:

Go to the target's `Info.plist` and change the following keys.

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>ASETNIOP</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>ASETNIOP</string>
```

**Advanced setup** would employ localization for your custom keyboard extension display name.

- Go to your Xcode project and select your **keyboard extension target**
- Go to *General* tab and set *Display Name* to `${PRODUCT_NAME}`
- Go to *Info* tab and set `CFBundleName` to `${PRODUCT_NAME}`
- Make sure `CFBundleDisplayName` is set to `${PRODUCT_NAME}`

  > Now, this setup allows you to set the Keyboard appex's name from a single place -- *Build Settings* tab
- Go to *Build Settings* tab and search for `PRODUCT_NAME`. Edit *Product Name* to be **ASETNIOP**
- [Localize `Info.plist`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) and add these keys to respective localizations:

  ```
  "CFBundleDisplayName" ="ASETNIOP";
  "CFBundleName" = "ASETNIOP";
  ```

Comment: I made a single change - to Bundle Display Name in the info.plist for the extension - and it seems to have done exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Editing `CFBundleName` might be optional for your task, and the key can have other value if needed. However, I am not aware of any example when this might be desired.